# Tikz : how to write a vector composed of Feynman graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I managed to write this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1cm]
\node at (-3.4,-1}
{$\begin{pmatrix}\mathcal{F}^{(s)}_+\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha_1,\alpha_{\i    nfty}\\ \alpha_z,\alpha_0
\end{matrix}\right](z) \\ 
\mathcal{F}^{(s)}_-\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha_1,\alpha_{\infty}\\ \alpha_z,\alpha_0
\end{matrix}\right](z)\end{pmatrix}$};

\node at (-1.65,-1){$=$};

\coordinate[label=above:1] (e1);
\coordinate[below=of e1] (aux1);
\coordinate[left=of aux1,label=left:$\infty$] (e2);
\coordinate[right=1.7cm of aux1] (aux2);
\coordinate[above=of aux2,label=above:z] (e3);
\coordinate[right=of aux2,label=right:0] (e4);

\draw[line] (e1) -- (aux1);
\draw[line] (aux1) -- (e2);
\draw[line] (e3) -- (aux2);
\draw[line] (aux2) -- (e4);
\draw[line] (aux1) -- node[label=below:q] {} (aux2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center},
```

which gives me

[image]

but on the r.h.s I want to create a vector with the same kind of feynman graph.

I really don't know how I can create a vector with feynman graphs, aligned in an equation. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question but LaTeX considers any `tikzpicture`  like any other character or box. Therefore, you can easily build an array/tabular/matrix with its elements being tikzpictures.

[image]

Previous figure was done correcting some mistakes on your code, like missing `\begin{document}\end{document}` or `\usepackage{mathtools}` (or `amsmath`).

Instead of trying to build an equation inside a `tikzpicture`, what I've done has been including two `tikzpictures` inside an equation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}\mathcal{F}^{(s)}_+\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha_1,\alpha_{\infty}\\ \alpha_z,\alpha_0
\end{matrix}\right](z) \\ 
\mathcal{F}^{(s)}_-\left[\begin{matrix}\alpha_1,\alpha_{\infty}\\ \alpha_z,\alpha_0
\end{matrix}\right](z)\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=above:1] (e1);
\coordinate[below=of e1] (aux1);
\coordinate[left=of aux1,label=left:$\infty$] (e2);
\coordinate[right=1.7cm of aux1] (aux2);
\coordinate[above=of aux2,label=above:z] (e3);
\coordinate[right=of aux2,label=right:0] (e4);
\draw[thick] (e1) -- (aux1);
\draw[thick] (aux1) -- (e2);
\draw[thick] (e3) -- (aux2);
\draw[thick] (aux2) -- (e4);
\draw[thick] (aux1) -- node[label=below:q] {} (aux2);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=above:1] (e1);
\coordinate[below=of e1] (aux1);
\coordinate[left=of aux1,label=left:$\infty$] (e2);
\coordinate[right=1.7cm of aux1] (aux2);
\coordinate[above=of aux2,label=above:z] (e3);
\coordinate[right=of aux2,label=right:0] (e4);
\draw[thick] (e1) -- (aux1);
\draw[thick] (aux1) -- (e2);
\draw[thick] (e3) -- (aux2);
\draw[thick] (aux2) -- (e4);
\draw[thick] (aux1) -- node[label=below:q] {} (aux2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Sorry for my mistakes, I am not yet used to that stuff. Thanks a lot!